# Team Viewer 11 keyboard issue

Tags: teamviewer

I am currently logged into Team Viewer 11. My work computer will not accept any commands from my home keyboard. The mouse works just fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect from a Windows to a Mac computer? I have realised that when I use a Windows computer and try to connect to a Mac that a lot of the keyboard command don't work for example caps lock or shift (so I can't have any upper case letters at all).

Comment: Speculative observations like this would be better as a comment than an answer.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment on a question - to be honest I did try to!